# Using parameterization of a circle to find all integer solutions to $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm self-studying algebraic geometry through this [book](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf) and am stuck right at the start.

The author states that to find all $X, Y, Z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$ one can simply use this parameterization of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$:

$$x = \frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2 + 1}, y = \frac{\lambda^2 - 1}{\lambda^2 + 1}, \text{ where } \lambda = \frac{x}{1-y}.$$

Which, the author continues, leads directly to the fact that all solutions are given by:

$X = 2lm$, $Y = l^2 - m^2$, $Z = l^2 + m^2$, with $l, m$ coprime.

I don't follow this line of reasoning at all -- how he got the parameterization, what he means by setting the parameter $\lambda$, and how all that leads to the final assertion -- which I verified by computer is indeed the set of integer solutions.

I'm also interested in how I would do this over $\mathbb{Q}$, and for arbitrary curves. The first problem in section 1 is related to proving something similar for a circle of radius 5 over the rationals :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take lambda to be the slope of the line that passes through the circle. It intersects the circle at two points (1,1) and the second point say (x,y). If lambda is known,the point (x,y) can be found by using the equation of a line where a slope and co-ordinates of one point is known.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the circle and show the $x$- and $y$-axes. Look at a point $(x,y)$ on the circle. Draw the line that passes through that point and through the point $(0,1),$ which is also on the circle. The slope of that line is $-\lambda = (y-1)/x.$ Now we have a system of two equations:
$$
-\lambda = \frac{y-1} x \\[10pt]
x^2+ y^2 = 1
$$
The solution for $x$ and $y$ is what you wrote.

Observe that $x$ and $y$ are rational if and only if $\lambda$ is rational. Thus letting $\lambda$ run through $\mathbb Q$ gives all rational points on the circle (except $(0,1).$) (And this shows that there are infinitely many rational points on the circle and thus infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples. I don't know a simpler way to show that.)

Letting rational $\lambda= \dfrac \ell m$ with $\ell,m\in\mathbb Z,$ we have
\begin{align}
x & = \frac{2\lambda} {\lambda^2 + 1} = \frac{2\ell m}{\ell^2 + m^2} 
\end{align}
and then treat $y$ similarly.

Comment: A simple way to show that there are infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples is to construct an infinite family. I think this observation is often made by schoolchildren: for any odd number $k$, the triple $k, \frac{k^2-1}{2}, \frac{k^2+1}{2}$ is a Pythagorean triple. For example, $(3,4,5), (5, 12, 13), (7, 24, 25), (9, 40, 41),\ldots$